# Isabelle Nitpick cardinality limit of 65536 exceeded; what to do?

Tags: isabelle

I'm getting this `Limit reached: too high cardinality (65536)` error from Isabelle's Nitpick tool:

```
Nitpicking formula...
[...]
The type 'a passed the monotonicity test; Nitpick might be able to skip some scopes
Using SAT solver "MiniSat" The following solvers are configured: "MiniSat", "SAT4J", "SAT4J_Light", "Lingeling_JNI",
"CryptoMiniSat_JNI", "MiniSat_JNI"
Trying 1 scope:
  card 'a = 4
Limit reached: too high cardinality (65536); skipping scope
Nitpick checked 0 of 1 scope
Total time: 63 ms
```

Questions:

- Is there a parameter I can change, to lift this limit?
- Is there anything else I might do?

Further information:

The property being checked involves finding filter bases on a topology with four points.  This means we're searching for an element (a filter) in a space with $2^4=16$ elements.  There are of the order of $65536=2^16=2^{2^4}$ such spaces.

Thank you.

Comment: a memory limit, so what can you reduce?

Comment: The limit is hardcoded in the Isabelle source code in HOL/Tools/Nitpick/nitpick_kodkod.ML, so maybe Kodkod limitation?

Comment: Thank you @MathiasFleury.  I looked at the source code and as far as I can tell it's coming from the use of an `int` type.  I'm running the downloadable binary Isabelle2022.  Do you think if I compile my own binary from source on a 64 bit system, I might get a higher limit?  Is there a compile flag I could set to force use of a large `int` type?

Comment: ML ints are already 32 bits by default. So this should not be the problem.

Comment: I think the best way to go is to ask on the mailing list if anyone remembers why this limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, [the maintainer of nitpick answered](https://isabelle.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/247541-Mirror.3A-Isabelle-Users-Mailing-List/topic/.5Bisabelle.5D.20Nitpick.20hardcoded.20limit.20of.2065536.3A/near/380943735) and:

> I'm afraid your problem is really too big for Nitpick. Not only it hits a
> technical limit imposed by its backend, Kodkod, problems of this size even
> if they were accepted by Nitpick would be much too big to be solvable.